# Is it possible to change a list of URLs in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a site that has around 20 internal links I'd like to change.

Is it possible in jQuery to change these whenever they appear?

So, for example, if the site outputs:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/link1">Link</a> or <a href="mysite.com/link2">Another</a>
```

jQuery changes this to:

```
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/link">Link</a> or <a href="www.externalsite.com/link-another">Another</a>
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to JS/jQuery.

Comment: Yes. It's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
//Specify what you want to replace with what, here:
var changes = [
    ['http://www.mysite.com/link1', 'http://www.othersite.com/link'],
    ['http://www.mysite.com/somepage.php', 'http://www.othersite.com/anotherpage.php'],
    ['http://www.mysite.com', 'http://www.anothersite.com']
]
```

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
        var href = this.href;
        for(var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++){
            if(href == changes[i][0]){
                href = changes[i][1];
            }
        }
        this.href = href;
    });
});
```

Comment: You missed the part where /link1 changes to /link and /link2 changes to /link-another

Comment: You also missed the part where there are two different domains being used (externalsite.com and othersite.com). There doesn't seem to be a "set of rules" that the user is looking for. It looks very custom.

Comment: @Dutchie432: well, how about that?

Comment: That's pretty sweet my man. `for(k in replace)` should probably be `for(k in changes)` - otherwise a solid solution. Also, if you did a direct comparison rather than a replace, you would not need to worry about the order you put the changes into. In otherwords, `if (href == changes[k][0]) href = changes[k][1]`

Comment: @Dutchie432: It was a invalid object, silly me, changed it to an array.
Will edit in the check.

Comment: Good update, but `href.replace(changes[i][0], changes[i][1]);` should just be `href = changes[i][1]` unless I am missing something. Your code will work, but a `replace()` is more costly of resources and not needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. [Here is a Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLH5k/)

```
​$​('a').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    link = link.replace('www.mysite.com', 'www.othersite.com');
    link = link.replace('mysite.com', 'http://www.externalsite.com');
    $(this).attr('href', link)    
});​​
```

Since it seems that you have very specific links you want to substitute for your current links, you'll need to adjust this to handle all of the specific changes. This example simple handles a domain text replacement. It's hard to gather specific "rules" from the example you provided.

If you only have a handfull of links, perhaps hard-coding the substitutions is better.

```
​$​('a').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var newLink = null;
    if (link == 'http://www.mysite.com/link1') 
        newLink ='http://www.othersite.com/link';
    else if (link == 'mysite.com/link2') 
        newLink ='www.externalsite.com/link-another';

    if (newLink) $(this).attr('href', newLink)    
});​​
```

Comment: Great thanks, yes they are very specific, not really much of a pattern as there are lots of links that need to change to anchor links on an external site